# Displaying Data from array in TableView is not working in swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to display some data from an array into a tableView in swift 3.
I created 2 controllers, One controller named as TableViewCell which has the labels declared and one controller with the function.

```
class FlightContro: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var fetchDetails = [Details]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var allFlightsArray = [AnyObject]()
    var carrierArray = [String]()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        parseData()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

     // API 
    func parseData(){
        fetchDetails = []
        let urlString = "APIURL"
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { ( data,response, error) in
            if(error != nil){
                print("Error")
            }else{
                do{
                    let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary

                    for index in 0...data.count-1 {
                        let aObject = data[index] as! [String : AnyObject]
                        let aObject1 = aObject["data"] as! [String : AnyObject]
                        let category = aObject1["category"] as! String
                        let aObject2 = aObject1["flightInfo"] as! [String : AnyObject]



                        self.allFlightsArray.append(aObject2 as! AnyObject)


                    }


                    for flight in self.allFlightsArray{

                        self.carrierArray.append(flight["flightCarrier"] as! String)
 }

                    print(self.carrierArray)
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })


                } catch{
                    print ("Error 2")
                }
            }

    }
        task.resume()


}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

func  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.destination.text = "text"
        return cell
    }


}
```

This is my main controller
import UIKit

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var destination: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var company: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var terminal: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

printing all the data from the API is working very well but I cannot display it in the table view, I tried many times and it is not working.

Comment: Add UITableViewDelegate too

Comment: `cell.destination.text = "text"` you don't use `allFlightsArray` or `carrierArray` at all? Is `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` even called? Where is set the datasource/delegate of your tableView?

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection returns 10, func  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    } cell.destination.text = "text" is for testing to see if is working, I used cell.destination.text = self.carrierArray[indexPath.row] but is not working too

Comment: Why do you cast `aObject2` first to a dictionary and then to (more unspecified) `AnyObject`? Upcasting is pretty silly in this case. By the way do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift anyway. Apart from that a JSON dictionary in Swift 3  is `[String:Any]`. And **never** hard-code `numberOfRows...` in a dynamic table view.

Comment: because the JSON wasn't in the right format, casting aObject2 actually allows me to get the right data that I needed. NSDictionary doesn't affect nothing at this moment and I can be able to change it later..  I have done the change in the function so now calls the array.count ... What could be the problem here? Seems like still is not working..

Comment: With the code you show in your question, are you currently getting 10 rows of the word "text"? Or are you getting Zero rows?

Comment: Zero rows, it doesn't displays nothing because if was displaying text I would've be able to display the data from the json.

Comment: @MikeMixy - have you set a breakpoint or added debug print() statements to *confirm* that the table functions are actually being called? Is it possible you simply didn't connect the DataSource and Delegate from your tableview to your class?

Comment: @DonMag - I haven't. I will check it again today and I will with an update.